# Linux app for tracking work hours

Tags: linux

I am looking for an app to track my working time. Tons of time tracking apps exist, but none of them suits my needs. I want:

- For a specific day add several entries as work time, e.g. „09:00 - 11:15“, „11:45-14:00".
- The app should calculate my required time (5 days per week * 6 hours) and calculate if I worked overtime.

I *don’t care* about tracking time for which projects I worked which amount of hours on - that seems to be what most tools are about. However, none of them seem to have overtime calculation.
Also, I don’t need time tracking for billing.

Ideally it is a terminal based app so I can use it over SSH.